# window.opener is not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, window.opener

I am accessing variable from parent to child window using `window.opener`. It works in IE and Chrome but not works in Firefox. Below is line of code that we use:

```
// to set the value in parent page
window.opener.varA = "TEST#1234";


//get the value in child page

varA =  window.opener.varA;
```

But it return `varA` as undefined in Firefox and return the `varA= "TEST#1234"` in Google Chrome and IE. Can anyone help me on this how can I get the value of `varA`?

Comment: Why are you using `window.opener` to set the variable in the parent page?

Comment: because we want value of some of variable parent page to child page to perform some operation

Comment: Yes, but since you're setting the value from the parent page, you should not have to use `opener` on that side. `window.varA = "TEST#1234"` should do. Unless I failed to understand your question?

Comment: We tried to access the using window.varA but still it return null but it works in IE and google chrome. Any help on this.

Comment: Any help on above my problem. it is very critical we stuck on this.